# Add small extra gps antenna on tracker installed inside aluminum tube

Tags: antenna, gps

I would like to install a GPS tracker inside a scooter. Will the GPS signal will be lost if I install the tracker inside the vehicle?
Can I add a small extra antenna to fix outside the scooter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because where to place a GPS antenna on a terrestrial vehicle is not related to space exploration.

Comment: This group https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is better for your question.